# .htaccess - how to disable a magic_quotes when I don't have access to php.ini

Tags: php, .htaccess, magic-quotes-gpc

I would like to disable a magic quotes on my page. I don't have access to php.ini...
When I try add to my .htaccess this line: 
`php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off`

I get: **500 Internal Server Error**. In my index of errors, I found this:

```
[Mon Nov 25 23:49:16 2013] [alert] [client MY_IP] /home/USER/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://my-page.pl/index
```

I know, I can add this code after '< ?php':

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

but I'm not convince to this tip. Have you got any ideas for me?

Comment: Is your php handler suPHP?

Comment: Where I can check it?